# geom_tile finding the proper height of tiles

Tags: r, ggplot2, height, heatmap

I am plotting a heatmap with

```
ggplot(param, aes(V2,  V1,z=V7))+ geom_tile(aes(fill = V7, height=0.02))
```

But my V1 is not equally spaced. How can I find the proper height? Beacause height=0.02 might be too large for some small value, so that they are covered by other.

Can you give me an example how to do that? E.g. The V1 value are like:

1, 0.8,0.7,0.45,0.3, 0.12,0.07,0.0004

So i need to find the differences of each pair of values. But the min height is different to the max height. I read that the tile is going from -h/2 to h/2 for height h. But the min height is of course different to avoid gaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends (heavily) on what you are trying to represent. If there is some inherent height (e.g, the range over which the value should apply) you should use that. That is, if each measure is a point measure over a small area, that is the area that should be used.

If, however, all you want to do is make the bars touch each other, that can be done, but will have to be done outside the call to `ggplot`. (Note also: the interpretation of your graph may be off a bit, as larger gaps will imply that some measures cover wider areas than others, and those bars will not be centered on the true location.)

Using `dplyr` you can simply calculate the midpoint between two measurements and use that as the boundary between your points. Then, use `geom_rect` instead of `geom_tile` to pass in those boundaries directly. Note that this assumes some things about your range of values since you did not post any data:

```
sampleData <-
  data.frame(
    x = c(1,2,3)
    , y = c(0.01, 0.1, 1)
    , z = c(1,2,3)
  )


sampleData %>%
  mutate(ymin = (y + lag(y, default = 0))/2
         , ymax = (y + lead(y, default = 1.5))/2
         , xmin = x - 0.5
         , xmax = x + 0.5
         ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(xmin = xmin
             , xmax = xmax
             , ymin = ymin
             , ymax = ymax
             , fill = z)) +
  geom_rect()
```

[image]

Here is an example using multiple `x` locations. Note that here, instead of averaging to get the `ymin` and `ymax`, I explicitly set them to the edges I want:

```
sampleData <-
  data.frame(
    x = rep(c(1,2,3), each = 3)
    , y = c(0.01, 0.1, 1
            , 0.04, 0.3, 0.9
            , 0.2, 0.5, 0.8)
    , z = c(1,2,3)
  )


sampleData %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  arrange(y) %>%
  mutate(ymin = (y + lag(y))/2
         , ymax = (y + lead(y))/2
         , xmin = x - 0.5
         , xmax = x + 0.5
         , ymin = ifelse(is.na(ymin), 0, ymin)
         , ymax = ifelse(is.na(ymax), 1.25, ymax)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(xmin = xmin
             , xmax = xmax
             , ymin = ymin
             , ymax = ymax
             , fill = z)) +
  geom_rect()
```

[image]

Comment: I see right now that this gives problems if you have several same y values?

Comment: The `default = 0` is not needed (and not advised) because you are explicitly setting the NA's to a meaningful value (the external range). You could certainly do the same thing for the x-axis, though I cannot conceive of a way to do both at the same time and get anything meaningful to plot. The y-values are handled separately for each x location. If you have identical y's at a single x-axis point, this is the wrong plot to be making anyway.

Comment: Thanks. My dataframe is structured such that for every x value there is the same y value:

Comment: so that for every y group there are the x values. Because in a function plot for a horizonatl line ther are also "Many" x values for one y values so to say ...;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! It worked! But dont't I need the default=0 in lag and lead in your last example because I get NAs?

And is it analoge to unequal sopaced x values like for the y values?

Answer (score 0):

According to the structure of my data:

the data is column wise and for every y there are the x values:

y x   z
1 0.1 #
1 0.2 # 
1 0.3 #
1 0.4 #
3 0.1
3 0.2
3 0.3
3 0.4

etc e.g.